# How to share Vim spellchecking additions between multiple machines?

Tags: spell-checking

I use Vim's spellchecking feature. Given that I work with many technical terms and LaTeX commands, I tend to add many them to my personal dictionary in `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add`.

I would like to share this file across multiple machines, so that when I add a word to the file on one machine, it is also added on other machines, and I don't need to add it once on each machine. I tried versioning `~/.vim/spell/en.utf-8.add` in git, but this does not seem to work: vim does not pick up the new terms. I suspect that Vim also needs the file `en.utf-8.add.spl` to be edited somehow, but as this file is binary, versioning it will probably lead to conflicts.

Does anyone here have a satisfactory solution to have vim spellcheck dictionary additions as part of their config, and synchronizing them between all of their machines?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Vim uses the `spl` file to do the checks, and the `spl` file is generated from the `add` file.  We can speculate on whether the `spl` file is portable across different machines and Vim versions, but it's easier (and safer) to re-generate it as needed.  Now, the `spl` file is re-generated automatically when you add words to your local dictionary from within Vim, but you must run `mkspell` to re-generate it if you edit the `add` file directly.

With that in mind, you can do something like this: synchronize the `add` file by whatever means (with `git`, `rsync`, NFS, or whatever), and add these commands to your `vimrc` on all machines:

```
for d in glob('~/.vim/spell/*.add', 1, 1)
    if filereadable(d) && (!filereadable(d . '.spl') || getftime(d) > getftime(d . '.spl'))
        exec 'mkspell! ' . fnameescape(d)
    endif
endfor
```

This will re-generate the `spl` file at Vim startup whenever the corresponding `add` file is newer than it.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks! I added `silent` before `exec` so I don't get spammed at startup by the progress info of the command (and don't get "Press ENTER or type command to continue").

Comment: @a3nm That's a matter of preference.  As an senior sysadmin explained to me many years ago, being spammed with "ok" notifications is a sign things work fine. :)

Comment: By the way, if you are also using this setup, you probably want to automate the handling of git conflicts. I explained how to do that here: https://a3nm.net/blog/git_auto_conflicts.html

Comment: @Cbhihe: *You've completely missed the point.* `glob()` is a builtin Vim function that (as the name suggests) performs the equivalent of Bash pathname globbing. That is, `glob()` accepts a glob expression and returns a list or string of all pathnames matching that expression on the local filesystem. Glob expressions are like regular expressions, only simpler and less powerful. Type `:h glob` within Vim for gruesome details.

Answer (score 6):

I've created a [Vim plugin](https://github.com/micarmst/vim-spellsync) for this. It finds the path to the spell folders automatically and then calls `mkspell` on any word lists it finds at startup to regenerate the spell files.  It also creates `.gitignore` and `.gitattributes` files in the spell directories to exclude binary spell files and to use Git's [union merge driver](https://web.archive.org/web/20181009034917/https://krlmlr.github.io/using-gitattributes-to-avoid-merge-conflicts/) to avoid conflicts when merging spell files from two different machines. Thanks to [Sato Katsura](https://vi.stackexchange.com/a/5052/19028) for the `mkspell` example.

https://github.com/micarmst/vim-spellsync

Answer (score 0):

I sync my .vim folder to my machines using Dropbox. Whenever I've made a change to my configuration, I'll throw it back onto Dropbox and pull it down on my other machines.

I have the commands set in my .bashrc file so I can save some typing. My Vim install isn't too complex, so it's pretty quick to sync when I make a change. Not sure how it'd handle an exceptionally large .vim folder.

Comment: Thanks for this suggestion! However, Dropbox is proprietary software, so it don't want to be using it. (It forces me to worry a lot more about its security, and it doesn't offer confidentiality guarantees of what I store in it.)

Comment: Avoid "dropbox". Use `git` versioning instead.